# How do I follow up on the results of a question I've asked?

Tags: discussion

I've asked a [bunch](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/compression-clothing) [of](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/how-long-should-a-well-maintained-chain-last-and-what-can-i-do-to-prolong-its-lif) [questions](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/do-mudguards-help-if-so-what-are-the-best-for-a-fixie-commuter) that I have either followed up the advice given or am about to. I'd like to provide an update on the outcomes. Is the best way to just edit the question with my new information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply edit the question with the new information; updates should naturally go at the bottom of the question, unless the nature of the question has radically changed.

Remember that we [retain all edits in revision history](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) and anyone can see the date of post, and the date of the last edit *directly* on the post itself.

I also recommend leaving *comments* on the answers indicating any specific followup or commentary on how those answers turned out for you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend something like:

```
 ## Update (2011-07-31):
 Tried out Bob and Alice's suggestions to fiddle with the whoozawhatzit
 and now the thingamagig is all out of whack.
```

Which will render like:

> ### Update (2011-07-31):
>
> Tried out Bob and Alice's suggestions to fiddle with the whoozawhatzit and now
>   the thingamagig is all out of whack.

Maybe also comments on the specific answers.

Comment: I think an <h1> is rather a bit much. Just a simple "edit: blah" is fine. The dates are in the revision history.

Comment: Personally, I prever an `<hr>` (renders as a gray line) followed by a bold heading. But as long as it's eye-catching it's all good. Does SE markup support the `<blink>` tag?